# Antlr remove left recursion while keeping math-expressions and bool-expressions separately

Tags: java, antlr, grammar, antlr3, left-recursion

I'm getting this famous error

> rule has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations

for following simple grammar.

```
expr
    :   INTEGER         
    |   '(' expr '+' expr ')'
    ;

bool_expr
    :   '(' bool_expr 'and' bool_expr ')'
    |   '(' expr '<' expr ')'
    ;

INTEGER
    : '0'..'9'+
    ;
WS  
    : (' ' | '\t' | ('\r')? '\n')+ {$channel = HIDDEN; }
    ;
```

I already went through following answers which were no help.

1. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6629397/help-with-left-factoring-a-grammar-to-remove-left-recursion) : I don't want to combine the mathematical expressions and boolean expression into one, so I don't have to verify it via AST. I'm trying to keep these two expression separately.
2. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985513/rule-has-non-ll-decision-due-to-recursive-rule-invocations) The Wikipedia is not helping me to understand this specific situation. And I don't think I can simplify this grammar than this.
3. [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13491982/antlr-left-factoring-grammar) Here I think we have a different situation.

I can't understand what is the left recursion here. I don't see any `A-->Ab|b` or something like that. Can anyone please help me to solve this.

Please note following.

- I don't have operator precedence, I always use parenthesis
- I don't want to combine two types of expressions
- If anyone interested, this works correctly with ANTLR4

Comment: Is there a particular reason you're using ANTLR3? ANTLR4 probably accepts this grammar without any problem.

Comment: @Bart Kiers Yes. Later I need this in C++. And I think ANTLR4 is not supporting C++ targets. Isn't it ?

Comment: Btw, I have checked with antlr4 and it accepts this grammar and parses it correctly. And I have updated the answer with it

Comment: Why the redundant parentheses?

Comment: @EJP The language syntax is not defined by me. So I have to use those.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have '(' at the begining of the two alts in bool_expr.

`A-->'('AB|'('B` is contains also a problem of recursivity. @see the generated parser.

The solution is to add the backtracking option to your grammar:

```
options {
backtrack=true;
}
```